# How to find closest number in C?

Tags: c

So, I was working out some exercises from a recommended beginner's book: [C Programming: A Modern Approach (2nd Edition)](http://knking.com/books/c2/index.html) While working out one of the questions I found myself unable to proceed, as I couldn't **return the number closest to the user's input.**
*Note: The question was asked before loops, functions and arrays were covered, thus I am assuming that these should not be required.*

I managed to extract and simplify the problem to the following. Lets say I have the following numbers, and I want to return the number closest to the user's input:

`10` `20` `30` `40` `50` `60` `70` `80`

```
printf("Enter a number to find closest value: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

For example:

`User's input: 28`
`Closest number: 30`

Next, I decided to find the difference between `num` and each of the numbers by subtracting from each.

```
difference1 = num - 10;
difference2 = num - 20;
```

and so on. (I am not using loops as these have not yet been covered in the book)

I taking into consideration, negative differences (25 - 40 = -15). If the difference is less than `0`, I am multiplying the difference by `-1` to get all the differences to a positive integer. By doing so I will be able to compare the differences successfully:

```
    if (difference1 < 0) {
    difference1 = difference1 * -1;
}
```

Next I am checking for the minimum difference in order to identify which was the closest number by doing:

```
if (difference1 < difference2) {
    min1 = difference1;
}
else {                  
    min1 = difference2;
}

if (difference3 < difference4) {
    min2 = difference3;
}
else {
    min2 = difference4;
}

if (difference5 < difference6) {
    min3 = difference5;
}
else {
    min3 = difference6;
}

if (difference7 < difference8) {
    min4 = difference7;
}
else {
    min4 = difference8;
}

if (min1 < min2) {
    min5 = min1;
}
else {
    min5 = min2;
}

if (min3 < min4) {
    min6 = min3;
}
else {
    min6 = min4;
}

if (min5 < min6) {
    min = min5;
}
else {
    min = min6;
}
```

I know this is a very long method, however I was unable to shorten the code without the use of a for-loop.

```
printf("Difference between the two numbers is %d\n", min);
```

Since `min` contains the difference between the user's input and the closest number I am unable to find a way to print the number closest to the user's input.
How can I trace the minimum difference to the **original number** which this was subtracted from ? Any suggestions would be appreciated, and please excuse the basic nature of this question.

Comment: How can we do imperative programming without loops?

Comment: Loops make the program faster and much shorter, however what I am trying to achieve here can be done without the use of loops. If any suggestions utilise loops I will surely be grateful as I am only looking for the concept/idea behind the problem.

Comment: I understand that you do not want to use loops and arrays is that correct?

Comment: Without loops, arrays and functions you would need another set of variables, say `val1..val8` containing 10..80 that you manipulate "in parallel" with `min1..min8`.

Comment: @Rishi, correct. @ John Hascall that was an idea as well and I have the extra set of variables containing the values that I am matching the user's input to. The manipulating "in parallel" part is where I am getting stuck. At least, now I know that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you to make the code shorter.

Here are my approach

```
int num = 71;
int diff,ans;
int div10 = (num / 10);
int lower = div10 * 10;
int upper = (div10 + 1) * 10;
if(lower<10) lower=10;
if(lower>80) lower=80;
if(upper<10) upper=10;
if(upper>80) upper=80;
int diff1 = lower - num;
int diff2 = upper - num;
if(diff1 < 0) diff1 *= -1;
if(diff2 < 0) diff2 *= -1;
if(diff1 < diff2) {
    ans = lower;
    diff = diff1;
}
else {
    ans = upper;
    diff = diff2;
}
printf("ans=%d, diff=%d\n",ans,diff);
```

Comment: We don't know what the user input is going to be.

Comment: @Rishi: it's only an example. You can change it to any number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I would do:

```
int main(){
    int closest;
    int temp;
    int a0 = 10, a1 = 20, a2 = 30; //and more..
    int user_input = 28;

    closest = abs(user_input - a0);
    temp = abs(user_input - a1);
    if (temp <= closest)
        closest = temp;
    //and so on
    return 0;
```

}

Where abs is absolute value. Numbers should be in some data structure, because in the mean time you should ask if you still have something to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with 10s this should be quite simple:

```
num += 5;
closest_10 = num/10;
closest_10 *= 10;
```

Then you can have simple look up if you have an array of numbers. You can expand this to other multiples using a similar algorithm (say for 8s just replace 5 with 4 and 10 with).

Answer (score 0):

As all numbers are fixed, the best approach (at least the most efficient once compiled) is to use the following snippet of code:

```
int closest(int number)
{
    switch(number) {
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
        return 0;
    case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
    case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14:
        return 10;
    ...
    case 95: case 96: case 97: case 98: case 99: case 100:
        return 100;
    } /* switch */
 } /* closest */
```

Even more efficient if you can inline the code instead of writing a function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to better define: **Lets say I have the following numbers**.

How many numbers is the big question.  Your example has them all as evenly divisible by 10.  Your numbers are 10, 20, 30, and so on, and you mention a total of 8 numbers.  Is it only 8 numbers maximum?  Can they be any number?  Will they all be integers?  If its all integers and all divisible by 10, then you can use the **modulo** or **modulus** operator instead of subtraction.
The mod operator `%` only works on integers.

```
int a, b, c;

a = 3;
b = 25

c = a % 10;   /* c will equal 3,  0 / 10 = 0 with remainder 3 */
c = b % 10;   /* c will equal 5, 25 / 10 = 2 but remainder is 5 */

/* check if a number is even, just mod by 2 if zero then even */
if ( ( b % 2 ) == 0 )
    printf(" value in b is even number\n");
else
    printf(" value in b is odd number\n");
```